# VB click javascript button/img

Tags: javascript, vb.net, onclick

**Hi i am trying to click a button on a website with VB.NET**

The Command i use in .AHK is

```
Pwb.document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[7].click
```

The button/Img HTML is below.

```
<img width="34" height="34" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="doSubmit()" alt="" src="../../images/SC5Login07.jpg" border="0" complete="complete"/>
```

I noticed that it is running a some javascript when its clicked. That is below

```
function doSubmit() {
            //Submit the form
            if (document.getElementById("txtDBName").value == "") {
            //Login security modifications - End
                alert('You must select a Database');
            }
            else {
                if (document.getElementById("txtUserName").value == "") {
                    alert('Please enter your Tesseract user id and password');
                }
                else {
                //Set txtformEvent
                    document.getElementById("txtFormEvent").value = "onSubmit";
                    //Submit the form
                    document.getElementById("frmLoginLaunch").submit();
                }
            }                   
        }
```

Now i am aware that there is a GetElementById but i cant get that to work due to the lack of an ID. I was hoping it would be as easy as it is in AHK but it is not seeming that way.

*Basically is there a way to call this dosubmit() function or simulate clicking the image?*

Hope someone can help
Thanks

**Thankyou Guys this is my login code now**

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://caan/SC5/SC_Login/aspx/login_launch.aspx?SOURCE=ESOLBRANCHLIVE")

    While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtUserName").SetAttribute("value", "kieranw")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtPassword").SetAttribute("value", "kieranw")

    Dim allImgTags As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
    If allImgTags IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each img As HtmlElement In allImgTags
            If img.GetAttribute("src").Contains("/images/SC5Login07.jpg") Then
                img.InvokeMember("Click")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next img
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What is your problem!

Comment: Your `img` tag doesn't have any direct method call.  Most likely `doSubmit` is being called via a `form` tag.

Comment: *Basically is there a way to call this dosubmit() function or simulate clicking the image?* Well, yes, but in relation to what?

Comment: Are you waiting for the document loading to complete before issuing the click command?

Comment: @Ron at the moment I do not need to wait for page to load as it is one does the navigating and the other will hopefully soon submit the web form and log me in

Comment: Okay, then all you should need to do is call InvokeMember("click") on the element as my answer illustrates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say if your VB program was a web app, Console app, etc. but if you can use jQuery, then you can just do:

```
$("img[src$='SC5Login07.jpg']").trigger('click');
```

or:

```
$("img[src$='SC5Login07.jpg']").click();
```

EDIT:  It looks like you are using Winforms (which is not the best choice for this sort of thing, IMO).  In that case, try something like this:

```
Dim browser As New WebBrowser
browser.Navigate("your_intranet_url")

While browser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
  Application.DoEvents()
End While

Dim allImgTags As HtmlElementCollection = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
If allImgTags IsNot Nothing Then
  For Each img As HtmlElement In allImgTags
    If img.GetAttribute("src").Contains("/images/SC5Login07.jpg") Then
      img.InvokeMember("Click")
      Exit For
    End If
  Next img
End If
```

EDIT #2:  ron tornamb's code is closer to the original AHK code, so if you want to find the img by index, use:

```
Dim browser As New WebBrowser
browser.Navigate("your_intranet_url")

While browser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
  Application.DoEvents()
End While

Dim img As HtmlElement = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")(7)
If im IsNot Nothing Then
    img.InvokeMember("Click")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: right, sorry im new to all this. im pretty good with AHK but trying to learn VB.net.  I am currently doing this in Visual Express winforms. and it will be an app based and ran from a local computer which will control internet explorer which in turn will be browsing the web site.   I would give a link to the website too but unfortunately it is on the local intranet

Comment: Any reason you are using Winforms for this?

Comment: basically I press a button on the form to navigate to the page then press a button to login. Obviously this can and will be condensed down into one function eventually. Overall I will have several buttons  that will do various things

Answer (score 0):

To perform a click in VB.Net, you first need to wait for the document to load and then issue an InvokeMember("click") command on the element as follows:

```
Private Sub Pwb_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles Pwb.DocumentCompleted
    Dim elem As HtmlElement = Pwb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("IMG")(7)
    elem.InvokeMember("click")
End Sub
```

Comment: This will work, but since it uses an index to find the element, if an img gets added to the page at some later date, it could break the functionality.

Comment: True enough, but else would you suggest to find the element since it has no real distinguishing characteristics?

Comment: The only useful characteristic it really has is the src, so I used that one.  It also has height and width, so he could use any combination of those to find it.  I suppose that those could change as well, but IMO they are less likely to change than the img tag's index.

Comment: THere is no guarantee that more than one element shares the same image associated with it - or size for that matter.

Comment: I agree, just like there is no guarantee that the element will have an index of 7.  He should use whichever one is more likely to be correct for the page in question.  If the index is 7 and it isn't likely to change, use the index.